# React useCallback not updating when dependency changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

`useCallback` keeps capturing the wrong value of its dependency.

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  const callback = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log(state); // prints 0 why???????
  }, [state]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(1);
    return () => {
      callback(); // only called here, clearly after the state is set to 1
    };
  }, []);
```

I would expect to be able to access everything inside the `useCallback` dependency list from inside the `useCallback` callback with no issues.

What's the difference to not using useCallback if both produce the same output:

```
  const callback = () => {
    console.log(state); // prints 0
  };
```

Note: This also does not work, hence "effect callback is capturing the "wrong" callback." is false.

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setState(1);
    return callback;
  }, []);
```

**useCallback is clearly not capturing the correct values for its dependencies**

This works but is not what I want:

Using a ref instead of a state (React.useRef) works and calling the state's setState function and accessing the previous from inside that call also works. But I don't want to do either, I want to access the state directly as the state should be up to date according to the docs.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good use of `useCallback()`. There is no point in wrapping the state setter

Comment: That's not the question!.

If we don't provide a minimal reproducible example, it's not enough and if we provide a minimal reproducible example it's bad!

This is just an example. The question is about why the callback is not receiving the latest state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: No. This has nothing to do with setState but with state itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `useCallback`, that works and has the right dependencies.

The problem, in both the version with `useCallback` and the one without, is that you are calling `callback()` from the cleanup function of an effect hook, and *that* effect callback is capturing the "wrong" `callback`.

> I want to access the state directly as the state should be up to date according to the docs.

No, the `const state` does not (and cannot) update. See also [The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572), the "stale closure" problem and the [`useEvent` proposal](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/blob/useevent/text/0000-useevent.md#basic-example). You really need the `useRef` to access the current state from the old closure created at the first render, there's no way around it.

Comment: `No, the const state does not (and cannot) update` of course it does. It prints 1 if I use `setState((prev)=>{console.log(prev);return prev;})` but this is not the issue anyway so let's focus on the issue.

Comment: `and that effect callback is capturing the "wrong" callback.` I edited the question. Returning the callback itself instead of a wrapper callback also does not work.

Comment: This is simply an issue with useCallback not capturing the correct values for its dependencies.

Comment: According to the docs `By wrapping handleSubmit in useCallback, you ensure that it’s the same function between the re-renders (**until dependencies change**)` and this is exactly what I need. If the dependency is going to be old, then what's the point of the dependency list? https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback#usage

Comment: @FreeDomSy You are missing the issue. Of course using `return () => callback()` or `return callback` does not make a difference. It is the `() => { setState(1); return … }` callback, which you are passing to `useEffect`, that is capturing the wrong `callback` - the one that was created in the render cycle that caused the effect to run.

Comment: @FreeDomSy You can try adding the `callback` to the dependency list of `useEffect` to see what's going on.

Comment: This actually works! But it causes `useEffect` to be called twice (because `callback` reinitializes with the correct dependencies).

In this example, this is fine because the second call sets the state to 1 which it's already set to 1, but if you're doing something else (which my real app does) it makes it very problematic.

But I think this is on the right track.

Comment: I'm thinking about it again. Maybe it just doesn't work any other way since `useEffect` **HAS** to re-set the value of `callback` every time `callback` changes to the new value and there's no way around this! useRef is the solution I think.

Comment: @FreeDomSy yes, that's what I'm saying. Or wait, my answer didn't actually *say* it, editing…

Comment: You can write an answer and I'll mark it as accepted. It might be useful for other.